# Django flatpages app will not work

Tags: python, django

I have Django 1.6.4 and Python 2.7. I am running on Windows 8. I am following along with the book Practical Django Projects (2nd ed) and in the very first projects it says to add

```
'django.contrib.flatpages',
```

into Installed Apps in the settings.py. It then instructs you to run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

When I do this I get an error:

> CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
>
> flatpages.flatpage: 'sites' has an m2m relation with model: , which has either not been installed or is abstract.

I went into the Django documentation for version 1.6.1 (the closest thing to what I have, 1.6.4) and followed the instructions for flatpages:

To install the flatpages app, follow these steps:

> Install the sites framework by adding 'django.contrib.sites' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting, if it’s not already in there.
>
> Also make sure you’ve correctly set SITE_ID to the ID of the site the settings file represents. This will usually be 1 (i.e. SITE_ID = 1, but if you’re using the sites framework to manage multiple sites, it could be the ID of a different site.
>
> Add 'django.contrib.flatpages' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.

Then either:

> Add an entry in your URLconf. For example:
>
> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>       (r'^pages/', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
>   )

or:

> Add 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware' to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting.
>   Run the command manage.py syncdb.

I have tried all of these things and it still doesn't seem to work. I don't understand what this error message is saying because 'django.contrib.sites' was already in my Installed Apps.

**Update:** Here is what my Installed Apps currently looks like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
)
```

Comment: How does `INSTALLED_APPS` look currently?

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to put the code in the comment properly, so I amended my original post. Please see above...

Comment: Try adding `django.contrib.sites` before the `django.contrib.flatpages` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I have no idea why it wasn't listed there anymore, I must have mixed up this settings.py with another one I was working on, because I swear it was there. That worked perfectly.

Comment: @Janden Glad your issue is solved. You can put code in the comments between two `\`` characters.